# ConstraintLayout chain context menu no longer visible in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, menu, android-constraintlayout

Using Android Studio 3.4 Canary 9 and 10
ConstraintLayout 2.0.0.alpha3

I am having an issue with constraint layout in the bleeding edge build of Android Studio 3.4 canary 9. Basically, when you click on a view in constraint layout, say on a chain element, you should be able to see small icons appear that allow you to perform certain actions on the views.

[image: Constraint Layout wth context menu buttons]

As you can see, under each view are 3 buttons that allow you to change the chain settings. However, this is what I get in my layout editor on 3.4.C09 when clicking on an element in a chain:

[image: Missing context menu in 3.4.C09]

Did they get disabled or moved elsewhere? Is this a bug? I have looked everywhere in the IDE without any luck, tried zooming in / zooming out, changing the theme, invalidating caches/restart, clean rebuild etc.

Thank you for any help provided!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Now you should see `Circle Chain mode` option in right-click menu in Android Studio 3.6.

[image]

---

According to the official response, this function has been removed in AS3.4.
But there seems to be no alternative. I have reported this problem to Goole and you can track [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138144293).

For now, you can add `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle` attr in xml manually. And after that `Cycle chain mode` options will appeare in the right-click menu.

Answer (score 4):

It is now available in attributes under **layout_constraints**. ( AS 3.5 )

[image]